# Amazon’s SNS API exchanged information via HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Amazon’s SNS API exchanged information via HTTP/HTTPS? 
Please let me know which communication ports it is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) to communicate with AWS SNS using its API like this:

```
http://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Name=My-Topic&Action=CreateTopic&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Timestamp=2010-03-31T12%3A00%3A00.000Z&AWSAccessKeyId=key&Signature=gfzIF53exFVdpSNb8AiwN3Lv%2FNYXh6S%2Br3yySK70oX4%3D
```

Consult official SNS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/Welcome.html